# Can I pass a pointer to myself in a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I have an object (type Cell) which stores a list of pointers to other objects of the same type (neighbours to it on a grid).

This is a 2D grid.. as a visual, see below:

```
xxc
xcc
ccx
```

The "c" in the very centre would be an alive cell, and it has to the north east, east, south and south west of it. It's neighbour list would have pointers to these cells, and then Null pointers in the other directions. It would look like this:
neighbours = {null, pointer, pointer, null, pointer, null, pointer, null) 
(order of the list is North, East, South, West, NorthEast, SouthEast, SouthWest, NorthWest).

If a new cell moves into its neighbouring position, for instance moves to the west of this cell, it would now look like this:

```
xxc
ccc
ccx
```

I need to update the neighbour list so it now has a pointer to its Western cell, and then the western cell needs to update all its neighbours to say "hello! I'm here! You now have me as a neighbour". So the Western cell would go through its own list of pointers, and on each one say "update your list with ME as your neighbour". I'm trying to pass in the "me" pointer as a pointer to itself.  Here is the code..

```
int Cell::updateAllNeighbours(){
    //Need a pointer to myself...
    Cell * temp = &this; //how do I do this???
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_NEIGHBOURS; i++){
        if (neighbours[i] != NULL) {
            if (i==0)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(2, temp);
            else if(i==1)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(3, temp);
            else if(i==2)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(0, temp);
            else if(i==3)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(1, temp);
            else if(i==4)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(6, temp);
            else if(i==5)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(7, temp);
            else if(i==6)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(4, temp);
            else if(i==7)
                neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(5, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to call the updatedNeighbour function and say "in position x [the number], you need to put this pointer to me in your neighbour list". I'm not sure how to pass a pointer to myself though.

Any thoughts? Sorry this is so confusing...

Comment: Sure.  But it's `this`, not `&this`.

Comment: Too much explanation for such simple question! Hit the nail with some minimal sample.

Comment: Oh my goodness you are right. I couldn't find it on the net so I assumed it was some wild thing and people would have no idea what I meant... Thanks paulsm4

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer, not a reference.  So this (no pun) code:

```
Cell * temp = &this;
```

Should be:

```
Cell * temp = this;
```

Beyond that, you don't need `temp` at all, it seems:

```
if (neighbours[i] != NULL) {
  if (i==0)
    neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(2, this);
  else if(i==1)
    neighbours[i]->updatedNeighbour(3, this);
  // etc...
```